# Stop user from sending multiple emails

Tags: php

Is there are reliable way of stopping a user from sending multiple emails in one go?

I have a basic html form which allows the user to type in an email address:

```
email1@address1.com
```

This works fine and the email gets delivered.  However, the user can also do this:

```
email1@address1.com, email2@address2.com, email3@address3.com
```

My code sends all 3 emails when the submit button is pressed.  How do I stop that from happening.  I want to restrict the user and only allow him/her to send 1 email per submit.

The code I currently have is this:

```
<?php

    $email_from = "oshirowanen@localhost.com";
    $email_to = $_POST["referred_email"];
    $email_subject = 'test subject here';
    $email_message = $_POST["referred_message"];

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '. $email_from ."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '. $email_from ."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $result = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

    if ($result) echo 'Mail accepted for delivery ';
    if (!$result) echo 'Test unsuccessful... ';

?>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried using split to get the first item in the array, but don't know how easy that is to hack, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that `$email_to` is a valid e-mail address before sending the mail. The easiest way to do that is probably to use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (!filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to evaluate the content of the inputfield: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Or just use the new email type for an input field: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp